# SVG scaling and maintaining its position relative to a div

Tags: html, css, svg, electron, scaling

I am currently trying to add these SVG knob icons I made into an electron app using flexbox. The catch is that they need to stay positioned in the center of the rectangle icon no matter the browser size, [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGOkL.png). So ideally, as the browser dimensions change, they stay confined to that rectangle and maintain their proportions within it.

Right now, as the icon scales from changing the browser window dimensions, the icons' positions over and under-shoot relative to the box, [illustrated here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qonr7.gif)

Currently, I have set the browser window of the app so that it maintains a constant aspect ratio.

Here is my relevant HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="container" class="app-graphics">
    <img src="/X/Electron/smoothiebro1/img/Rectangle 2.svg" id="blenderOutline">
    <!-- Made the width = 91% for the svg below, 
         because it was width of the bottomBar / width 
         of the "blenderOutline" -->
    <div id = "barDiv"> 
      <img 
        src="/X/Electron/smoothiebro1/img/bottomBar.svg" 
        id="bottomBar" 
        class="container" 
        width="91%"
      > 
    </div>
    <div class="flexContainerKnobs">
      <ul class="flexContainerKnobs">
        <img src="img/Knob1.svg" id="knob1" class="knob" width="13.32%">
        <img src="img/Knob1.svg" id="knob2" class="knob" width="13.32%">
        <img src="img/Knob1.svg" id="knob3" class="knob" width="13.32%">
        <img src="img/Knob1.svg" id="knob4" class="knob" width="13.32%">
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden
}

#blenderOutline {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
}

#bottomBar {
  position: absolute;
  border: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom: 3%;
  left: 5%;
}

#barDiv {
  text-align: center;
}

.flexContainerKnobs{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  margin-top: 108%;
}

.knob{
margin: 0 auto;
}

ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 16px;
}
```

[Here](https://ronsoros.github.io/?4db0ac270997eb4b330ac8532d426f5723386af2) is my SVG, the code for it was too long to include in the post.
An important detail which I can include here though is the SVG's  viewbox, which is: "0 0 72 66.5" In the above code, I made the widths for the images ~13% because that was the ratio of the width of the SVG to the width of the background (in percent form).

Comment: whare your whole code in codepen.io

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta i can't unfortunately because I'm using electron :/ but there are desktop versions of codepen/fiddle for electron if you want

Comment: have you tried decreasing width of img tags

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta yes, the same result keeps occurring and it won't stay in its position

Comment: Are you saying that it fails in Electron, but you can't reproduce it in a browser?  Please create a [mcve]. You can include your SVG by reducing it to just a cricle.

Comment: Also, your SVG link seems to be wrong.  Plus you have two SVGs in your code. Where is the other one?

Comment: My first inclination is to think it's a problem with setting your `ul` to `position: absolute`, width no relative positioning on its parent. Not to mention, `ul`'s ned `li`'s. Your markup is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

I would change your markup to this (removing the `<ul/>`)

```
<div class="flexContainerKnobs">
  <img src="img/Knob1.svg" id="knob1" class="knob" width="13.32%">
  <img src="img/Knob1.svg" id="knob2" class="knob" width="13.32%">
  <img src="img/Knob1.svg" id="knob3" class="knob" width="13.32%">
  <img src="img/Knob1.svg" id="knob4" class="knob" width="13.32%">
</div>
```

and update the css for that div to this:

```
.flexContainerKnobs{
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 108%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```